# Chrome wont keep an extension when downloading a .csv file from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, export-to-csv

Our application takes data from our display table and downloads it for the user in .csv format without the user needing to name it. This used to work but in the last few days Chrome must have changed how they do it. I can't find anything online about the change or possible fixes. Now Chrome opens a save file dialog box and their default filename has no extension. Any ideas on how to get it to at least allow the javascript to specify the extension or avoid the save file dialog completely?

Chrome version: 35.0.1916.114

Our code is this:

```
factory.export = function (columns, people, wednesday, name) {

    var d = new Date(wednesday);
    var strDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();

    var exportName = strDate + ' ' + name;

    var dataToSend = [];

    // push the header
    var header = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < columns.length; k++) {
        header.push('\"' + columns[k] + '\"');
    }
    dataToSend.push(header);

    // push the body
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        for (var j = people[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            people[i][j] = '\"' + people[i][j] + '\"';
        }
        dataToSend.push(people[i]);
    }

    var csvContent = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF'; // this last part is to make the characters get encoded correctly

    dataToSend.forEach(function (infoArray) {
        var dataString = infoArray.join(',');
        csvContent += dataString + '\n';
    });

    exportName += '.csv';
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute('download', exportName);

    link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
};
```